# Converting array of Matplitlib dates to Datetime objects with NaN

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I have thousands of files with irregularly data that I am trying to interpolate to the same grid. The data is stored in individual `numpy` arrays for a number of different variables and times. I have been interpolating the times using `matplotlib.dates` by converting times to numbers. But because I don't want to extrapolate missing data the interpolation has introduced `np.nan` values in the dataset that makes the conversion from `matplotlib` date to `datetime` object tricky because I need to conserve shape (i.e. can't remove `np.nans`) but `md.num2date` cannot handle masked arrays or `np.nan`.

Is there another command like `md.date2num` and `md.num2date` in another library that can account for `nan`s? Or is the only solution here a `for` loop?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as md

tdata = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 736926.9827155,736926.98274578,736926.98276768,736926.98285067,736926.9828712])

#Allows num2date to work but removes the nan values and won't conserve shape
test1 = md.num2date(tdata[~np.isnan(tdata)])

print(len(tdata),len(test1))

#Using a mask will produce an error 
#test2 = md.num2date(np.ma.masked_array(tdata,np.isnan(tdata)))
```

Note that I need the shapes to be the same and that `np.nan` could occur anywhere in the array. I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
test1 = np.full_like(tdata, np.nan, dtype=object)
test1[~np.isnan(tdata)] = md.num2date(tdata[~np.isnan(tdata)])
```